# Streamlining Exception Handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, try-catch

I'm creating an asp.net site that populates a database. My goal is to print success/fail messages for each database operation. Currently I have try catch statements for each drop, insert and create statement. My question is: can I create a single method that performs exception handling where it is passed a method call e.g:

```
public void doWork()
{
  if(exceptionHandling(calculateStuff()) != null)
  {
    div.innerHTML += "there was a problem (print error)";
  }
}

public Exception exceptionHandling(methodCall)
{
  try {
   //execute method call
   calculateStuff();
  }

  catch(Exception error)
  {
    return error;
  }

  public void calculateStuff()
  {
    //calcuate stuff here
  }
}
```

My aim is to reduce repetition in my code by reducing the number of try/catch statement. Is the above an acceptable way of doing it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

You can always do the following (I've modified your code slightly that it no longer returns an `Exception`, but instead the calling code provides the code to call on exception; it's a question of readability for me, you can hopefully modify this if you prefer your approach):

```
public void SomeOperation(MyObject param)
{
   //do something
}

public void SomeOtherOperation(AnotherObject param)
{
   //do something else
}

public void SafelyExecute<TParam>(Action<TParam> methodToExecute,
                                  Action<Exception> exceptionHandler,
                                  TParam param)
{
    try
    {
        methodToExecute(param);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        exceptionHandler(e);
    }
}

public void DoWork()
{
   SafelyExecute(SomeOperation,
                 e => div.innerHTML += "there was a problem" + e.Message,
                 myObjectInstance);
   SafelyExecute(SomeOtherOperation,
                 e => div.innerHTML += "there was a different problem" + e.Message,
                 anotherObjectInstance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can definatly do it and my suggestion would be to use **Postsharp** which you can download from nugget and it works like a charm ..For example have a look at below code

```
/// <summary> 
/// Aspect that, when applied on a method, catches all its exceptions, 
/// assign them a GUID, log them, and replace them by an <see cref="InternalException"/>. 
/// </summary> 
[Serializable] 
public class ExceptionPolicyAttribute : OnExceptionAspect 
{ 
    /// <summary> 
    /// Method invoked upon failure of the method to which the current 
    /// aspect is applied. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <param name="args">Information about the method being executed.</param> 
  public override void OnException(MethodExecutionArgs args) 
    { 
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid(); 

        Trace.TraceError("Exception {0} handled by ExceptionPolicyAttribute: {1}", 
            guid, args.Exception.ToString()); 

        throw new InternalException( 
            string.Format("An internal exception has occurred. Use the id {0} " + 
            "for further reference to this issue.", guid)); 
    } 
}
```

and to use this just put attribute on ur method as below :-

```
[ExceptionPolicy]
public void doWork()
{
  ///Your code
}
```

so whenever error will occure in dowork it will redirect to piece of code for exception handling.

For more information :-

http://www.postsharp.net/blog/post/Day-6-Your-code-after-PostSharp